# Build error referencing build.xml and proguard file: "null returned: 1"

Tags: android, cordova, proguard, build.xml, cordova-plugin-proguard

While building my PhoneGap app (with the Facebook SDK plugin installed), I encountered this error:

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occured while executing this line:
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Line 653 is:

```
<do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipp aidl/renderscript/R.java">
```

Line 698 is:

```
proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt"
```

My solutions so far include the following:

1. Ran `android update project` to force generation of the `proguard-project.txt` file, as well as update the `local.properties` and `project.properties` file.
2. Edited `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml` so that all mentions to `proguard.txt` become `proguard-project.txt`.
3. ran `ant -logfile ./antLogFile.txt release`. Here is the log file.

> -set-mode-check:
>
> -set-release-mode:
>
> -release-obfuscation-check:
>        [echo] proguard.config is C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
>        [echo] Proguard.config is enabled
>
> -pre-build:
>
> -check-env:  [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2  [checkenv] Installed at C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk
>
> -setup:
>        [echo] Project Name: HelloWorld   [gettype] Project Type: Application
>
> -build-setup: [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
>        [echo] Resolving Build Target for HelloWorld... [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.3.3 [gettarget] API level:        10
>   [gettarget] WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml
>   (14) is higher than the project target API level (10)
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HelloWorld... [dependency] Library dependencies: [dependency]  [dependency] ------------------
>   [dependency] Ordered libraries: [dependency]  [dependency]
>   ------------------ [dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Building Libraries with 'release'...
>
> nodeps:
>
> -set-mode-check:
>
> -set-release-mode:
>
> -release-obfuscation-check:
>        [echo] proguard.config is C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
>        [echo] Proguard.config is enabled
>
> -pre-build:
>
> -check-env:  [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2  [checkenv] Installed at C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk
>
> -setup:
>        [echo] Project Name: facebook   [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
>
> -build-setup: [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
>        [echo] Resolving Build Target for facebook... [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.3.3 [gettarget] API level:        10
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\brian.lee\Desktop\Eclipse Workspace\chumba_connect_trunk_new\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\rsObj
>       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\brian.lee\Desktop\Eclipse Workspace\chumba_connect_trunk_new\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\rsLibs
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Resolving Dependencies for facebook... [dependency] Library dependencies: [dependency] No Libraries [dependency] 
>   [dependency] ------------------ [dependency] API<=15: Adding
>   annotations.jar to the classpath.
>
> -code-gen: [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one. [mergemanifest] Manifest
>   merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
>        [echo] Handling aidl files...
>        [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Handling Resources...
>        [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
>        [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\brian.lee\Desktop\Eclipse
>   Workspace\chumba_connect_trunk_new\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\res/crunch
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698:
>   null returned: 1
>
> Total time: 2 seconds

All of my attempts yielded no progress. **Why does this error occur? What must I do to build successfully?**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Close Eclipse and then run `ant clean` in your project folder.

Comment: Doesn't help me... Exactly the same error, but only if I insert appcompat library project from the latest Google update. If I use the older appcompat, builds fine. Tried exiting IntelliJ Idea (as I'm not using Eclipse) and running manually ant clean - nothing... Happens with Ant 1.8.2 and 1.9.4. exactly the same error: ".../android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1"

Comment: Fixed. Conflicting build targets were at fault. Needed to change project.properties in appcompat directory to 'target=android-21', instead of android-19 which I had before.

Answer (score 4):

For me: I had

> edited my config.xml wrongly

. Try undoing your edits or placing a generic config.xml then see if she builds.

Answer (score 2):

Verify your `JAVA_HOME` variable is correctly set to some path like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\` and if the error still goes on, it may be solved going to the **build.xml** and setting *true* to the variable `fork`, or the passed variable `${need.javac.fork}`, which sets **fork**´s value in:

> fork="${need.javac.fork}"

Answer (score 2):

For me, conflicting build targets were at fault. Needed to change project.properties in my library directory (which was appcompat) to 'target=android-21', instead of android-19 which I had before. If you encounter a similar error and the previous answer (ant clean) does not work, check all the build targets.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to make sure your local.properties has the path to your sdk:
`sdk.dir=/path/to/adt/sdk`

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if the problem comes from your development environment or from a mistake in the project  i recommend everybody to try to create a new project from the cordova CLI.

- Open terminal
- Type `cordova create foo; cd foo;`
- Type `cordova platform add android`
- Type `cordova build`

Does it works? So the problem is on your project configuration. 
This was my mistake:
In order to add icons to the application I've create a folder called android inside `foo/plataforms/android/res/{android/icon*.png}

The correct way to add icons is to create the folder res in root of the project
foo/{res/android/icon*.png}

And then, add this files into the configuration file as follows:

```
<platform name="android">
              <icon src="res/android/icon@ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/icon@mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/icon@hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/icon@xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
     </platform>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, I solved it this way:

Go to the framework directory in the project, and type these commands to build the jar file (you will need to have `ant` installed to generate the jar file, but it should be on your system already):

```
android update project -p . -t android-23

ant jar
```

So just make sure what type of android you have because you may have tried `android-19`.