# android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Tags: android, ant, build

I'm trying to test a Android release build to make sure nothing unexpected occurs. While trying to build with ant from the command line:

```
/usr/local/bin/ant release
...

BUILD FAILED
.../android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
.../android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1
```

When I look at `build.xml:698`, the issue is with the Proguard file below.

```
<aapt executable="${aapt}"
    command="package"
    verbose="${verbose}"
    manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
    originalManifestPackage="${project.app.package}"
    androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
    rfolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
    nonConstantId="${android.library}"
    libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
    libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
    libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
    ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}"
    binFolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
    proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
    <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
    <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
</aapt>
```

My project had a `proguard-project.txt`. After renaming to `proguard.txt`, the problem persists.

I'm happy to omit the Proguard step since I don't use it.

How do I resolve this issue?

---

In case it matters:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
```

I needed to upgrade ant due to an error, but I don't recall what the error was. I seem to recall it had something to do with Java 7 or Java 8.

Comment: You have to look above. Often the reason is error inside `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 15):

Had the same error. found the fix at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23774435.
close eclipse. and run 'ant clean'

Comment: Doesn't help me... Exactly the same error, but only if I insert appcompat library project from the latest Google update. If I use the older appcompat, builds fine. Tried exiting IntelliJ Idea (as I'm not using Eclipse) and running manually ant clean - nothing... Happens with Ant 1.8.2 and 1.9.4. exactly the same error: ".../android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1"

Comment: Fixed. Conflicting build targets were at fault. Needed to change project.properties in appcompat directory to 'target=android-21', instead of android-19 which I had before.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using `ant` from the command line; and not from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

change project.properties in appcompat directory to 'target=android-21',  or Close Eclipse and then run ant clean in your project folder , if the first doesnt work

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using `ant` from the command line; and not from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Just happened to me and what I did to solved this is by removing the platform and re-adding it again.

```
cordova platform rm android
```

then

```
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this problem can be caused by many things, however in my case I couldn't build because of a malformed config.xml. I forgot to add the gap: namespace which was used to build with build.phonegap.com

```
<widget id="appid" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The problem is in the 64-bit library. Try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing some png files that I had in res folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the you are trying to install the Flutter SDK, and you encounter:

> error installing flutter null returned 1

just restarting the machine worked for me.